# Regex replace but exclude everything inside <title> </title>

Tags: regex

I want to use Regex to find all words matches in HTML code and then replace them with the links, but I need to exclude everything inside title tags.

HTML:

```html
<p> 
    This is Apple text.
</p>

<title>
    Apple is good for your health.
</title>
```

I want to replace:

```
Apple
```

to:

```
<a href="/search/apple">Apple</a>
```

Right now I am doing replacements with:

```
/>([^<]*)?(Apple)([^>]*)?</
```

Replace with:

```
>$1<a href="/search/apple">$2</a>$3<
```

But the result is

```html
<p> 
    This is <a href="/search/apple">Apple</a> text.
</p>

<title>
    <a href="/search/apple">Apple</a> is good for your health.
</title>
```

I need to exclude the word Apple inside title tag from being replaced.
Just like this:

```html
<p> 
    This is <a href="/search/apple">Apple</a> text.
</p>

<title>
    Apple is good for your health.
</title>
```

Please help.

Sorry for my English. Thanks for your help. 
I really appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you also do not want to replace Apple in `<!-- Here is an Apple -->` nor in `<input value="Apple">`, nor in `<script>class Apple {}</script>`, nor in `Applepie`, nor in `<a href="http://example.org/Apple">`, nor in `<style>.Apple { display: none }</style>`, ...etc, ...etc. Parsing HTML with regex is a ... disaster.

Comment: I haven't had that kind of hassle. Hmm ... but now it looks fine 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a negative lookahead to the regex, you can exclude title tags:

```
>([^<]*)?(Apple)([^>]*)?<(?!\/title)
```

See example: https://regex101.com/r/svErYD/1/

Comment: It's works. Thanks for make my life easier 